How can i run a C# test project from command line?
My main purpose is automation and running tests with MSBuild if it is possible. If it is not possible, the alternative is to run the tests with another command-line prompt and then view the results.
If possible, I would like to avoid using third-party packages.

The answers are with mstest which is deprecated and i get this message: 'mstest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

What Testing Framework is use? NUnit, xUnit all should have Test Runners.

I disagree with the dupe: It is really out of date and not useful anymore (imho).

Some more resources to check out for you @Ádam : dotnet test, Introducing the MSTest Runner – CLI, Visual Studio, & More, Unit testing C# in .NET using dotnet test and xUnit

@ÁdámBenák The latest answer suggesting vstest.console.exe should still hold true.

@Filburt This one? I fixed the formatting. I still think it's not the best go-to dupe nowadays ...

dotnet test works for me, thanks for the answers!

@Fildor For a better dupe (and there's bound to be plenty) OP should have to posted clearer specs. As it turned out, it was dotnet test they have been looking for because that's what they are targetting.

@Filburt Yes, I totally agree with that.
